# Which preposition to use with the verb ''market'' ? ''to be marketed at somebody'' or ''to be marketed to somebody''

Tags: prepositions

I was reading an essay and encountered this sentence;

''When computer games were invented, they were initially marketed at and played by the younger generation.''

When I looked up sentences with ''market at somebody'' I found nothing in either Oxford Learner's Dictionary or Cambridge Dictionary, but I found this on Oxford Learner's Dictionary;

''School meals need to be marketed to children in the same way as other food.''

Is it incorrect to write ''market at somebody'' ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was incorrect, just unusual. Presumably the sense is 'the marketing was directed at young people'.

Answer (score 1):

If you were talking about a discrete individual I would say "marketed at" would be very jarring, but when (like here) it is used with an amorphous group either "marketed at" or "marketed to" is okay.

Comment: Thank you! An ESL teacher just gave me this answer '''Marketed to' is used in the following context; Roblox are under scrutiny for marketing their latest battle game to children and young players. In this instance the product is being sold to a specific type of consumer.
'Marketed at' would be used in the following context; Tourism and municipal organizations are working together to develop a picture of the Capital that could be marketed at both the local and national level to attract tourism and businesses to the area. ''

Comment: But there the collocation is "at...level" rather than "market at".

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine. But they have a couple of differences of nuance.

To market something **at** someone or some market segment can convey the sense of the marketeer 'aiming' at that target from a distance.

Where one is marketing something **to** someone, the sense more often conjured up is one of the marketer 'bringing' or 'presenting' the relevant product to a specific audience.

Using 'at' sounds a little more impersonal (and perhaps more aggressive), while choosing the preposition 'to' lends your sentence a possible nuance of active close-up contact with the people for whom the product is intended.

You would be more likely to market (say) a cigarette brand *at* a particular target market, while a product intended to genuinely solve potential customers' problems will tend to be marketed *to* such customers.

Think also of the difference between throwing a ball *to* someone and throwing a ball *at* someone.

More generally, one tends to go *to* people (personally) and aim *at* targets (or people) impersonally and at a distance.